# How to make a pattern to match?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

Consider

```
DeleteCases[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}, {_, 3, __}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}}

i.e., keep only those lists that **don't** have `3` on their second position. That works well.

Now,

```
DeleteCases[{{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}, {__, 3, __}]
```

> {{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}}

gives only those lists that **don't** have `3` somewhere in the middle, i.e. on positions 2, 3 or 4 (or, in other words, keeps only those lists where `3` is in positions 1 or 5).

---

**Question**

How to make a general pattern/function that will keep only those lists (of arbitrary length `n`) that **don't** have a given number `a` on a specific position `k`($1\leq k\leq n$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented this function. For the cases I have checked it worked well.

`fun[list_, k_, a_] := DeleteCases[list, Table[_, k - 1]~Join~{a}~Join~{___}]`

For eg:
`fun[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {7, 8, 4, 3}, {1, 2}}, 3, 3]` gives 
`{{3, 2, 4}, {7, 8, 4, 3}, {1, 2}}`

Answer (score 11):

[`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) takes arguments to specify how many times a pattern should repeat.  Questions 1 and 2 didn't specify that there should be an element following the given number `a`, as in the opening example, so I wasn't sure whether `___` (no element needs to follow) or `__` (at least one element should follow) should be specified.  But it's easy to change.

```
(* matches if  a  is at end of list *)
pos[a_, k_Integer?Positive] := {Repeated[_, {k - 1}], a, ___};

DeleteCases[{{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3}}, pos[3, 3]]
  (*{{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}  *)

DeleteCases[{{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3}}, pos[3, 1]]
(*  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3}}  *)
```

For large arrays, a vectorized approach with numeric boolean operations will be more efficient.  Example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[3, {15, 5}];

Block[{k = 3, a = 3},
 Pick[data, Unitize[data[[All, k]] - a], 1] (* drops element if a is in k-th position *)
 ]
(*
  {{3, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 1, 3, 0}, {2, 0, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 3},
   {2, 0, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 0}, {2, 3, 1, 1, 1}}
*)
```

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** Per Mr. Wizard's recommendation, added additional checks

```
del[data_List, position_Integer?Positive, val_] :=
 DeleteCases[data, _?(Length[#] >= position && #[[position]] == val &)]

SeedRandom[1];

data = RandomInteger[10, {5, 10}]

(*  {{1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 4}, 
     {1, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1}, 
     {6, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1}, 
     {3, 5, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 9, 5, 1}, 
     {5, 2, 3, 9, 1, 0, 4, 4, 1, 5}}  *)

del[data, 3, 3]

(*  {{1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 4}, 
     {1, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1}, 
     {6, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1}}
```

Comment: This is the method I typically use, however consider adding a `Length` check to avoid e.g. `{1, 2}[[3]]`, i.e. `Length[#] >= position && #[[position]] == val`

Comment: An alternative one might use is `MatchQ[#[[position]], val]` instead of `#[[position]] == val`, and then `val` could be any pattern. One should beware that with `==`, elements will match that are sufficiently close numerically to be considered equal, whereas with `MatchQ`, they have to be exactly the same. So `==` will be a superior approach in some applications and not in others.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - edited per your recommendation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using Michael's data:

```
list = {{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3}};
```

Function definition

```
del[{e_, p_}][list_] /; list[[p]] == e := Nothing
del[_][list_] := list
```

Expected results:

```
del[{3, 3}] /@ list
```

{{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}

```
del[{3, 1}] /@ list
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3}}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
list = {{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {3}, {1, 
    2}, {3, 3}};

SequenceReplace[list, {{Repeated[_, 1], 3, b___}} :> Nothing]
```

> {{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3}, {1, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

Using Michael's data:

```
list = {{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3}};
```

Function definition using `Select`:

```
FilterByPositionValue[l_List, val_, pos_Integer] := Select[l, #[[pos]] =!= val &]
```

Testing `FilterByPositionValue`:

```
FilterByPositionValue[list, 3, 3]

(*{{3, 5, 7, 5, 2}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}*)

FilterByPositionValue[list, 3, 1]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3}}*)
```